# Triggering garbage collector in nodejs without implicit flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

I know a way to triggering gargage collector in nodejs by using `global.gc()` when you start `nodejs` with flag `--expose-gc`.
Is it passable to triggering gc without such flag?
For example: To triggering gc on an array we can use such syntax:
`array.lenght = 0`.
What about anonymous functions/objects/etc?
(I know about automatic memory management, just need to check, maybe here is a hide way/hack).

Comment: `array.length = 0` does not trigger GC or immediately free any memory.  It only makes something available for GC whenever the GC next decides on its own to run.  There is no other way to manually trigger GC other than using the command line parameter with `global.gc()`.  Perhaps if you explain what problem you're really trying to solve, we can help you better with that.

Comment: `>what problem you're really trying to solve.`


I've tried to solve a contest. Where's one limitation: 20MB. On small tests no problems. But when 100k/1mln input digits input/output stream keeps in memory something unused.
I don't have access to nodejs arguments. All what I can just send a source code.
(I don't care how ugly/strange code will looks like. Even if: create 1k array and delete all references.)

Comment: You'd have to show the actual API request you're using for us to know how to advise further.  I would say that if you have a choice of programming environment, then a garbage collected envirionment (like nodejs) is probably not the best choice for minimum peak memory use.